React useState with enum type produces string instead of number
I'm using a typed useState call to establish a state variable of enum type:
enum Direction
{
 None,
 North,
 South,
 East,
 West
}

const [direction, setDirection] = useState<Direction>(Direction.None)

This works and is typed correctly in typescript (in the IDE, I mean), but the actual type of the direction variable is string, and this fails in constructs like
var label: direction === Direction.None ? "Select a direction..." : direction.toString(),

because the direction variable is a string while Direction.None is a number.
I could use == instead, but I'd rather not, because the whole point of strong typing is that you don't rely on behavior like that.
Is there a way to make useState actually return an enum state variable of the correct type?
Update:
Indeed useState does correctly preserve the data type that you pass in, but I found the source of the problem: I was using the direction as a key in a component from a third party component that passed me the key in a callback, and it had converted the value to a string, and passing this key to setDirection is what caused the type to be wrong. Even with typescript protecting you, it's hard to defend against things like that.

useState does not do any sort of casting internally. Given your enum, direction should effectively be a number (though it would show up as a Direction type in the IDE. Are you sure you're referring to the same direction variable? Where does it say that direction is a string?

I tried writing typeof direction to the UI and it prints out string.

When you use enums without value, their values default to numbers like
enum Direction
{
 None, // = 0
 North, // = 1
 South, // = 2
 East, // = 3
 West // = 4
}

To use the enum with string values, all you have to do is assign the enums the string values that you want. Like:
enum Direction
{
 None=“None”,
 North=“North”,
 South=“South”,
 East=“East”,
 West=“West”
}

Edited:
You can have a look on this snippet on how it behaves with the details that you have provided
https://playcode.io/1882531

I want numeric values. The problem is that useState seems to set the direction variable to the string "0" not the number 0.

useState does not manipulate the value.  Are you sure no other manipulation is done?

also, consider providing more details so people can help out instead of just down voting an attempt to help you out with minimal info! The answer given above is not wrong, it just doesn't solve your issue and this is because of the poor question

What else would be helpful to know? In general I try to show the least amount of code that shows the issue, to avoid clutter.

You are saying that direction variable is a string. Where does this happen? direction is a state of type Direction so where was it initialised as string?

I found the problem: I was using the direction as a key in a component from a third party component that passed me the key in a callback, and it had converted the value to a string, and passing this key to setDirection is what caused the type to be wrong. Even with typescript protecting you, it's hard to defend against things like that.
